# Retornar informacion con ajax, php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Tengo este codigo que me extrae la informacion de un BD con ajax, pero cuando quiero mostrar esa información en unos campos especificos no me muestra

```
function searchInventorySales() {
    let name_product = document.getElementById('id_producto').value;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/manage/search_product",
        data: {
            name: name_product
        }
    })
        .done(function (respuesta) {
            {
                for (let i = 0; i < respuesta.length; i++) {
                    if (respuesta[i].nombre == name_product) {
                        error_sales_string = respuesta[i].nombre
                        document.getElementById('nombre_product').value = respuesta[i].nombre;
                        document.getElementById('precio').value = respuesta[i].valor_unitario;
                        previousAmount = respuesta[i].cantidad;
                        id_producto_sale = respuesta[i].idproducto;
                        document.getElementById('textWarning').innerHTML = `<h1 class="input-group-addon">En bodega quedan: ${previousAmount} 
                                                                            de este producto</h1>`
                        document.getElementById('id_producto').value = "";
                    }
                }
                if (error_sales_string != name_product) {
                    alert(`El ID ${name_product} no existe, intente con otro`);
                    document.getElementById('id_producto').value = "";
                }
            }
        });
}
```

El me retorna la informacion en la consola del navegador
pero no me pone esa info en los campos que requiero
Necesito ayuda con esto se los agradezco

Comment: Dentro del `done` pon un `console.log(respuesta);`, revisa la consola y agrégalo en la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. Agrega igualmente el trozo de HTML donde se encuentran los elementos que quieres modificar.

Comment: El error que veo aquí es que recorres los resultados con un ciclo y estás asignando los valores a elementos por ID que, supongo, están repetidos y, por tanto, se aplican siempre sobre el mismo.